# Issue with combobox when I bind using linq join query

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I am binding `ComboBox` using LINQ Join query. Below is my code:

```
var list = (from a in context.tbl_Products
            join c in context.tbl_CurrentStock on a.ProductID equals c.ProductID
            where c.Qty > 0
            select new
            {
                ProductID = a.ProductID,
                ProductName = a.ProductName
            }).ToList();

cmbProduct.DataSource = list;
cmbProduct.ValueMember = "ProductID";
cmbProduct.DisplayMember = "ProductName";
cmbProduct.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Table Details:
tbl_Products : ProductID, Product Name

```
Data in table

1,ABC
2,BCA
3,CDA
```

tbl_CurrentStock: StockID,ProductID,Qty

```
Data in table:

1,1,5
2,2,10
3,3,50
```

I am using cmbProduct.SelectedValue like below:

```
int ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(cmbProduct.SelectedValue);
var Product = context.tbl_Products.Single(o => o.ProductID == ProductID);
```

Until here it is fine. In combobox I have selected "ABC", but I am getting `cmbProduct.selectedvalue` value as 2 instead of 1. Same way if I select 2nd product getting value as 3 instead of 2, it is not giving selected value, instead it is giving first value in the list. What could be the problem? It's silly and eating my head. This is working fine, when I don't use JOIN Query (if I bind data from only one table)
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Side note: you're calling `.ToList()` twice on `list`

Comment: What event do you use to initialize the ComboBox?

Comment: Provide data for  both tables... else it becomes unclear..Thank you

Comment: Please update your question to show how you set the cmbProduct.SelectedValue

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with LINQ.

Comment: Quesion edited. Added more details.

Comment: Thank you All. Problem resolved after changing sorted property of combobox to false. Combobox is sorting the productnames but not product IDs. This was causing issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved after changing sorted property of combobox to false. Combobox is sorting the productnames but not product IDs. This was causing issue. –